# Does accuracy of the numerical solution of a PDE depend on the scaling of the variables?

Tags: numerical-methods, heat-equation, parabolic-pde

I am trying to solve the 1D heat equation numerically. I want to solve it with a time-step of 2 seconds. Should time step always be less than one? i.e. should $\Delta t \leq 1$?
Suppose our original equation is :
$\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\alpha^2 \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2}
\end{equation}$
If i make the equation dimensionless by introducing $\hat{t}=\frac{T}{T}$,$\hat{x}=\frac{x}{L}$, and $\hat{u}=\frac{u}{U_*}$, where $T$,$L$,$U_*$ are the total simultation time, length of the rod and ambient temperature respectively, we obtain the dimensionless equation as below:
$\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \hat{u}}{\partial \hat{t}}=\frac{\alpha ^2 T}{L^2}\frac{\partial^2 \hat{u}}{\partial \hat{x}^2}
\end{equation}$.
I am unable to understand if there will be a difference in the numerical errors (due to truncation of the Taylor series) when we apply a numerical method (say Backward Euler) for the first equation and for the second equation? Will the solutions differ if we scale back our solutions of the dimensionless equation back to the original variables?

Comment: Think about what the value of the diffusion constant will be in both cases. Then think about how good your approximation will need to be (i.e the time and spatial steps) in both cases. Also, why don't you try both methods and compare to see what happens. And have you heard of the CFL condition?

Comment: Yes trying both is what i am currently doing. But i couldn't find a conclusion by numerical analysis of the two methods. Also it is due to nature of the problem that i am trying to solve that i want to take a step size of 2 s. So my idea was to scale it down so that it becomes less than 1.

Comment: You aren't approximating the time derivative very well if you are taking $\Delta t = 2$. To be honest, I'm surprised your solution would converge at all.

Comment: Surprisingly , backward Euler(with centered difference in space grid) method is giving very accurate solution for $\Delta t=2s$ as compared to the analytical solution. However, forward Euler method fails for 2s and required a much smaller time step as expected.

Comment: If you are using the backward Euler scheme on the time derivative then the BTCS (Backward Time, Central Space) approach is _unconditionally stable_. I thought you were using forward Euler for some reason, which definitely wouldn't converge at $\Delta t = 2$. This is due to the differences between implicit and explicit schemes.